# Django How to return object.filter query results so I don't have to iterate through them

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to return only one result from a query and return it as an object so I can call its' attributes in my template without having to iterate over them.

Basically, I have a landing page that iterates a list of objects on table1 and creates a link for each one, like product listings. When I click on a link, it presents data from that object on the page. I want to also present data from the object on table2 that has the foreign key to the objects whose page I am currently on.

The problem is I am returning an iterable item from table2, so in order to present that data, I have to run a for loop. It only returns one item, so it doesn't make a difference in how the page looks, but I would like to accomplish the same thing without the for loop.

models.py

```
class Exercises(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    evolution = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['exercise', 'evolution'], name='exercise_evolution_UNIQUE')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Exercise: {self.exercise}\t Evolution: {self.evolution}"


class Units(models.Model):
    uic = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    unit_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    mcc = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    ruc = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    personnel = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['uic', 'mcc', 'ruc'], name='uic_mcc_ruc_UNIQUE')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"UIC: {self.uic}\tName: {self.unit_name}"

class ExercisePersonnel(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey('Exercises', models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Units', models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Locations', models.RESTRICT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I am trying to pass from ExercisePersonnel attributes into my template

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Exercises, Units, ExerciseEdl, ExercisePersonnel, UnitEdl
from .forms import RegistrationForm, AccountAuthenticationForms, ExerciseForm, UnitForm, ExerciseEdlForm, ExercisePersonnelForm

def exercise_detail(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request)
    ex_name = Exercises.objects.get(pk=pk)
    person = ExercisePersonnel.objects.filter(exercise=pk)
    print(person)
    print(ex_name)
    
    context = {
        'ex_name': ex_name,
        'person': person,
    }
    return render(request, 'exercise/exercise_detail.html', context)
```

These statements
print(person)
print(ex_name)

Result in this output when rendering the template for the exercise object 'Iron Dong'

> <QuerySet [<ExercisePersonnel: ExercisePersonnel object (1)>]> web_1
> | Exercise: Iron Dong     Evolution: 21-1

And this output for the object 'MEFEX'

> <QuerySet [<ExercisePersonnel: ExercisePersonnel object (2)>]> web_1
> | Exercise: MEFEX         Evolution: 21-2

this means that print(person) is returning a dictionary object, correct? How do I get it to return the object in the same way that print(ex_name) does?

my template

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h3>{{ ex_name.exercise }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col justify-right justify-content-end">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <a href="{% url 'exercise-edl' ex_name.pk %}">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >EDL</button>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <a href="{% url 'exercise-edit' ex_name.pk %}">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Edit</button>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
              </a>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Exercise?</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      Are you sure you want to delete this exercise
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
  
                      <form class="btn btn-danger" action="{% url 'exercise-delete' ex_name.pk %}" method="POST">
  
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete exercise">Delete Exercise</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row p-1 mt-1">
      <h5>
        Evolution: {{ex_name.evolution}}
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-1">
      <p5>
        Start Date: {{ex_name.start_date}}
      </p5>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-1">
      <p5>
        End Date: {{ex_name.end_date}}
      </p5>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-1">
      {% for p in person %}
      <p>
        {{p.quantity}}
      </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: But there can be multiple `ExercisePersonnel` instances for one `Exercises` instance though as you are using a `ForeignKey`. If there are necessarily only one related instance you should be using a [`OneToOneField` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) instead.

Comment: Is it possible to narrow the results down to one objects with a filter and then return that result the same way you would with objects.get? There will be instances when there are all multiple objects with the same foreign key, but I will still need to display info for one specific object from that group.

Comment: If there can be multiple instances then what is the problem with looping? I don't understand your problem on one hand you say there can be multiple on the other you say there can only be one. If you want to get the first object you can use the `first` method `Model.objects.filter(...).first()` which will give either the first object if it exists or `None`.

Comment: first() works, thank you! There isn't a problem with iterating, I just wanted to know a way to do it without iterating to make the code cleaner. Thank you.